# Angular - Mixed Content: The page at 'https Error

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing an App with Angular 7 (frontend) and Laravel (backend). I test the endpoint in POSTMAN, and it works. When I tried to Login to the application, I got this error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sandbox.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://sandboxbackend.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/api/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[image: mixed_error]

Environment

```
export const environment = {
 production: true,
 apiUrl:   'http://sandboxbackend.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/api',
};
```

login.component.ts

```
  onLogin(user: User): Observable<User> {

const request = JSON.stringify(
  { email: user.email, password: user.password }
);

return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, request, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((response: User) => {
      // Receive jwt token in the response
      const token: string = response['access_token'];
      // If we have a token, proceed
      if (token) {
        this.setToken(token);
        this.getUser().subscribe();
      }
      return response;
    }),
    catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
  );
  }
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the apiUrl in the environment file to https like so.

```
apiUrl:   'https://sandboxbackend.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/api',
```

Read more about **Mixed Content** error here- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

Comment: What if the API does not provide https connection, what do you do then?